# Login usability issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, ipad

Just trying the iPad app for the fist time.

The login screen wasn't like a normal app login screen.  Several issues:

1. No arrow buttons to move between email address and password
2. Pressing Return did not cause the login action
3. Bad password took me back to the screen where I chose my login provider, rather than leaving me at the SO screen

Comment: What iOS version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you tap on the return button, the keyboard focus will switch between the two. I think it's a bit unnecessary to have dedicated arrow buttons for a form with two fields.
2. This was a behavior that did not exist in iOS7; I went ahead and fixed it.
3. A bad password (or other login error) will now show you the login alert form again.

These changes will be available as of **beta version 1.1.0.131.**